# How to implement VAST-ad using MediaElementJS and Youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api, vast, vpaid

I try to implement VAST-ad, but it doesn't work. My code doesn't show VAST ad before playing video
Here is my code:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#id', {
                    playsInline: true,
                    vastAdTagUrl: 'url',
                    vastEnableSkip: true,
                    vastSkipSeconds: 3,
                    features: ['vast'],
                    vastAdsType: 'vast',
                    success: function(media, node, playerElement) {

                    }
                });
```

Here is links:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement-plugins/2.5.0/ads/ads.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement-plugins/2.5.0/ads/ads.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement-plugins/2.5.0/ads-vast-vpaid/ads-vast-vpaid.js"></script>
```

I have this error in Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mejs.ad-skip' of undefined
>       at Object.1 (ads.js:14)

Answer (score 0):

**Late Answer:**

What is the exact url in your code vastAdTagUrl: 'url'?

It needs to be xml. For the sample of xml, you can go to: https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/VAST_Samples/blob/master/VAST%203.0%20Samples/Video_Clicks_and_click_tracking-Inline-test.xml

Also, for the features, need to have ads too:
features: ['vast','ads'],